# Grunt (node) - How to show available tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, gruntjs, jake

While beeing used to using Rakefile, Cakefile and Jakefile, they all had some convenient way of listing the available tasks.

Like

```
jake -T 

jake db:dump      # Dump the database  
jake db:load      # Populate the database
```

..etc.

or even filtering
"jake -T dum", to only show "the "jake db:dump" task.

So, is there a way to do the same using grunt? 
I was thinking of maybe creating a default task that iterates the entire grunt config object and write it to stdout via console.log, but does someone know a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't want to answer my own question, but I came up with an extremely dirty hack.


`grunt -h | sed -e '/Available tasks/,/Tasks run/!d'`



Surely someone with experience can come up with something better? :)

Answer (score 19):

grunt --help lists available tasks, as per following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004624/list-grunt-js-tasks).

Example output

```
.....

Available tasks
             clean  Clean files and folders. *                                
              jade  Compile jade templates. *                                 
        web_server  A Web Server similar to Python's SimpleHTTPServer, with   
                 Cross-Origin Resource Sharing and No-Cache options. *
```

Comment: This is the right answer and should be voted to the top.

Comment: The answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20229531/3384609) is better

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know the only way (obviously without hacks) to show the available tasks is using the `-h` or `--help` option.

As you can see in [grunt-cli source](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/blob/master/lib/cli.js) they clearly take care about only `-h` (help), `-V` (version), and `-v` (verbose) options.

So, I think that currently you have to create your own custom task to reach your goal.

Answer (score 9):

There is a better way! I'm currently working on a separate plugin, [grunt-available-tasks](https://github.com/ben-eb/grunt-available-tasks) to achieve this functionality. Add it to your project with:

```
npm install grunt-available-tasks --save-dev
```

Then run `grunt availabletasks` to get a list of your tasks. You may want to alias this with `tasks` to save some typing:

```
grunt.registerTask('tasks', ['availabletasks']);
```

Then, with some configuration you can get lists like this one:

```
$ grunt tasks
Running "availabletasks" task

Deployment Tasks
doc                => Build the documentation.
production         => Build a complete distribution for production; stricter linting and a full browser test.

Development Tasks
default            => Build a development distribution.
watch               > Run predefined tasks whenever watched files change.

Done, without errors.
```

You can filter, group and sort tasks using a configuration object in your Gruntfile. A [comprehensive list of options](https://github.com/ben-eb/grunt-available-tasks#options) is available in the README.

Comment: Task "availabletasks" not found. Likely for the same reason that I'm trying to list available tasks (troubleshooting).

Comment: I think I posted this answer before I made the task a multi task; you'll need to do something like grunt.initConfig({ availabletasks: { tasks: {} } }); - find the rest of the options in the README. :-)