# List grunt.js tasks

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to work out how to print a list of all available grunt tasks. With rake it would be:

`$ rake -T`

What's the equivalent for grunt? e.g.

`$ grunt -T`

- concat
- jasmine
- minify

Answer (score 174, accepted):

`grunt --help` lists available tasks.

Comment: ha! I completely missed that, saw the top section of commands but didn't notice the tasks were listed at the bottom...

Comment: @tJener how to you list the tasks of a multi task: `grunt multi:task0`, `multi:task1`, etc.?

Comment: on a sidenote, a related interesting dicussion about being able to create a public or private task here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/741

Comment: @CiroSantilli I maintain a separate task listing module https://github.com/ben-eb/grunt-available-tasks which prints a task list, with multi-task targets, and without all of the noise that `grunt --help` generates. You might like to use it for now as a stop-gap, bearing in mind that it's been over a year since I first released it and still no option within grunt to hide tasks, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Workaround for the list in sh/bash in case you need to trigger something and can't modify the original code:

```
grunt -h --no-color | sed -n '/^Available tasks/,/^$/ {s/^  *\([^ ]\+\)  [^ ]\+.*$/\1/p}'
```

Comment: Sed program doesn't work:  "/^Available tasks/,/^$/ ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'

Comment: @gotofritz did you use single quotes? Double quotes have a different meaning check you sed documention otherwise. In case you use MacOs, it uses a different version of sed with a slightly different syntax.

Comment: Yes, I was on OS X. But don't worry about it, I hardly use grunt these days anyway :-)